# Configuration problem at: const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I know I made a mistake on line 23 because there are two `const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()` since I already used it on line 13.

This is what it gives me as a syntax error:

> SyntaxError non capturé /Users/ge.gourjon/Documents/bot discord/projet Athéna/index.js:23 const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()

My code:

```
const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()

    .setName("help")
    .setDescription("pour savoir toutes les commandes utilisables")
    .setName("moderation")
    .setDescription("pour avoir toutes les commandes de moderation")
    .setName("description")
    .setDescription("pour connaître la description du bot");


const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("calin")
    .setDescription("donner un calin à un membre")
    .addUserOption(option => option
       .setName("Utilisateur") 
       .setDescription("Utilsateur mentionné")
       .setRequired(true));


client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        if(interaction.commandName === "help"){
            interaction.reply("pour connaître mes commandes de moderation: /moderation");
        }
    }

});
client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        if(interaction.commandName === "description"){
            interaction.reply("Je suis Athéna, une déesse grec de l'artisanat et de la stratégie guerrière. Je m'occupe de la modération, jeux et de trackage d’information");
        }
    }

});
client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        if(interaction.commandName === "calin"){
            let user = interaction.options.getUser("Utilisateur");
            
            if(user != undefined){
                //<@id>
                interaction.reply.apply("Merci du gros câlin <@" + user.id + ">");
            }
            else {
                interaction.reply("Merci du gros câlin")
            }
          
        }
    }

});
```

What I want is to create the same command on line 23 as on line 13, i.e. a Slash Command. But when you do the Slash Command, you have to ID someone.

Answer (score 0):

To make a slash command where a user mention/id is required as input, you have to first make the command data. The way you created it with `SlashCommandBuilder` seems right, but I'll show you the object literal approach instead.

```js
import { ApplicationCommandOptionType } from 'discord.js';

// Type hint for VSCode Intellisense when writing object
/** @type {import('discord.js').APIApplicationCommand} */
const calinCommandData = {
    name: 'calin',
    description: 'donner un calin à un membre',
    options: [
        {
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
            name: 'Utilisateur',
            description: 'Utilsateur mentionné',
            required: true
        }
    ]
};
```

Now that you've constructed the command data, you need to register the command with Discord. The easiest way to do this is calling `client.application.commands.set` when you receive the `ready` event:

```js
import { Client } from 'discord.js';

// No intents are needed for responding to slash commands
const client = new Client({ intents: [] });

client.on('ready', () => client.application.commands.set([calinCommandData]));
```

Now we need to respond to the command when we receive it. Setup an `interactionCreate` event listener like so:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    // We only have chat input commands registered
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    // Get necessary properties from the interaction object
    const { commandName, options } = interaction;

    switch (commandName) {
        case 'calin': {
            // Pass true as the second argument since 'Utilisateur' is a required option
            // user will never be null/undefined
            const user = options.getUser('Utilisateur', true);

            // User objects turn into mentions when inserted into a string
            interaction.reply(`Merci du gros câlin ${user}`);
        } break;
    }
});
```

If you want to handle your other commands as well, add more cases to the `switch` statement:

```js
switch (commandName) {
    case 'calin': {
        const user = options.getUser('Utilisateur', true);
        interaction.reply(`Merci du gros câlin ${user}`);
    } break;

    case 'help':
        interaction.reply('pour connaître mes commandes de moderation: /moderation');
        break;

    case 'description':
        interaction.reply('Je suis Athéna, une déesse grec de l'artisanat et de la stratégie guerrière. Je m'occupe de la modération, jeux et de trackage d’information');
        break;
}
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the `import` statements I used above are ESM imports and only work if you have

```json
"type": "module"
```

in your `package.json`. If not, you can replace my `import` statements with this single CommonJS import:

```js
const { ApplicationCommandOptionType, Client } = require('discord.js');
```

Comment: I did exactly what you told me but it is written 'DEBUG CONSOL': (node:51379) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
What do I need to do please ?

Comment: I edited my answer, check the bottom for clarification.